# Meteor "email" package

Tags: email, meteor, smtp

I implemented a form, Once the user press submit, the input is sent to my email.

I installed email package but one thing i couldn't understand is that it requires something called `MAIL_URL` which has to be of this form `smtp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/`

If am not mistaken (based on my research) MAIL_URL is something called environment variable which i have created below (settings.json)

```
{
  "public": {
    "MAIL_URL": "smtp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/"

  }
}
```

My question is, what should i replace this line `smtp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/` with?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an email provider, for example mailgun or even gmail.

```
MAIL_URL: "smtp://behrooz.riahi:MEte0r1sAwes0me@gmail.com:587"
```

587 is for encryption. 25 is the standard unencrypted smtp port.

Comment: thanks, for "behrooz.riahi" will be my username that is stored in the database? and what about the password? i didn't understand what is "MEte0r1sAwes0me@gmail.com"

Comment: This URL defines the _sending_ account. Normally it is an account you set up just for your app and not for you personally - although you can use a personal account during testing. `MEte0r1sAwes0me` is just a fake password I made up.